# Is it possible to invoke php script automatically when someone upload file via ftp

Tags: php, file-upload, push-notification, ftp-client

Is it possible to invoke php script automatically when someone uploads file via ftp-client on our server.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?

Comment: Does this `php` file have to perform a generic task or actually be displayed to the user uploading the file?
There is no way that I know of to run a `php` file when a user uses ftp to upload a file and present it to the user, however if you this file is only required to run a generic task and not show any output to the user you can always run the `php` file from a cron and have the script check if there is a new file since it last checked.

Comment: I would say a cron job would suffice in you case.

Comment: Haven't looked into this too much, but something like: http://freecode.com/projects/kfsmd might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a port knocking daemon with iptables. Port knocking is an automate process to personalize ssh or ftp account. You can write a daemon to listen to iptables and run a php script when the right sequence of ports is knocked. I don't know if you can minimize the sequence to just one knock when you connect with a ftp-client.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have complete shell access to the server?
What you need to do is detect whether or not the contents of a folder has changed and have a script run.

If you're on Windows [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/11/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-script-any-time-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder.aspx) might be helpful.

If you're on *nix, have a look into [inotify](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) or [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)

Have them call a php script and away you go!

If you don't have complete control over the server, no doubt you can execute Cron Jobs. Have it execute a PHP script every x minutes that checks the contents of a directory, compares it to the contents it was x minutes ago and performs a diff between the two to find added or removed files.

Answer (score 0):

At linux you can use the watch command:

```
watch
Usage: watch [-bdhnptvx] [--beep] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--exec] [--help] [--interval=<n>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>
```

You can pipe the output to a piece of software actually handling the changes.